# VLOOKUP Help with Ranges

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have the following VLOOKUP in a cell on sheet1.

=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!B:C,2)

I assumed that this would attempt to return the corresponding value in column C on sheet 2 if it found a value in column B on sheet 2 that matched the value in I2 in sheet 1.

This doesn't seem to work though. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What **does** it do then - #N/A!? Check that you're looking up the same _type_ of data too. Looking up a text-formatted number won't match a numerical cell, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you need to add the 4th parameter - `range_lookup`. I always set this to `FALSE`.

i.e. `=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!B:C,2,FALSE)`

Comment: This parameter is optional, if omitted it is true, if you want to have only exact matches, then it should be set to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

With my Excel 2003 it is working, when I replace the "," by ";". Are there versions out there that exepts "," as divider between the parameters?

This is working for me:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2;Sheet2!B:C;2)
```

If you want to have only exact matches then you should use

```
=VLOOKUP(I2;Sheet2!B:C;2;FALSE)
```

Comment: That could be because on non-English Office, the argument separator is ; when compared to English MS-Office with , as the separator.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, I do have an english office, but my country setting is Germany, is it possible that this changes because of the country settings? OK, maybe because I use the "," for decimal numbers?